# Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'membersince' cannot be null

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I encountered this error :Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'membersince' cannot be null

here i tried to run my register page.

here are the codes. am i missing out anything? i checked my database table/input name were all correctly named "membersince" so what is really going wrong ? :(

```
   <?php                  
    require("config.php");
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 


       // =====================================================  

        // Check if the username is already taken
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 

            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This username is already in use"); } 


        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);      
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); } 



        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                nric = :nric 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( ':nric' => $_POST['nric'] ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);       
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This NRIC is already in use"); }  


                $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                mobilenumber = :mobilenumber 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( ':mobilenumber' => $_POST['mobilenumber'] ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);       
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This Mobile Number is already in use"); }  





        //---------------------------------------------------- Add row to database 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                name,
                gender,
                dateofbirth,
                nric,
                address,
                postalcode,
                mobilenumber,
                profession,
                membersince



            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email, 
                :name,
                :gender,
                :dateofbirth,
                :nric,
                :address,
                :postalcode,
                :mobilenumber,
                :profession,
                :membersince


            ) 
        "; 

        // Security measures
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); } 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'], 
            ':name' => $_POST['name'], 
            ':gender' => $_POST['gender'], 
            ':dateofbirth' => $_POST['dateofbirth'], 
            ':nric' => $_POST['nric'], 
            ':address' => $_POST['address'], 
            ':postalcode' => $_POST['postalcode'], 
            ':mobilenumber' => $_POST['mobilenumber'], 
            ':profession' => $_POST['profession'], 
            ':membersince' => $_POST['membersince'],
        ); 
        try {  
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 

            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        header("Location: successful.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to successful.php"); 
    }                              

?>
<!-- Author: Michael Milstead / Mode87.com
     for Untame.net
     Bootstrap Tutorial, 2013
-->




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Sign Up -</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>

<body>
  <?php 
if (empty($_SESSION['user']))
 {
 include_once("header.php");
 }
else     {
      include_once("header2.php");
      }?>

<div class="page-header">
      <div class="container">

    <h1> Register  </h1>


    <form action="register2.php" method="post" role="form"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="20" autofocus required/> 

        </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email: <strong style="color:darkred;">*</strong></label> 
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" maxlength="20" required/> 
              </div>

                             <div class="form-gtroup">
        <label>Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20" required/> <br /><br />
                                </div>

         <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" maxlength="20" required/> 
                           </div>





                                 <div class="form-group">   
                                 <label>Gender:</label> 
                         <div class="radio">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" required>
    Male
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" required>
    Female
  </label>
</div>  
            </div>  

                              <div class="form-group">  

                               <label>Date of Birth:</label>  
                               <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="" max="1997-12-31" required>   
                                   </div>


                        <div class="form-group">           
        <label>NRIC:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="nric" value="" maxlength="9" required/> 
                              </div>

                                 <div class="form-group"> 
        <label>Address:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="address" value="" maxlength="50" /> 
                               </div>

                                <div class="form-group">      
        <label>Postal Code:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="postalcode" value="" maxlength="6" pattern="[1-9]{6}" title="Postal code must be 6 digit!" required/> 
                          </div>


                                <div class="form-group">   
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">+65</span>
  <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="8" pattern="[1-9]{8}" title="Mobile Number must be 6 digit!" required>
</div>
 </div>



                    <div class="form-group">   
        <label>Profession:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="profession" value="" maxlength="20" required> 


                </div>         

                        <div class="form-group">   
            <input class="text" name="membersince" value=" <?php> $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d"); echo $todaysdate?>" type="text" disabled>
                       </div>                                                               

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register" /> 
         <input type="reset" class="btn btn-info" value="Reset">      


    </form>








</div>      
</div>                         

      <?php include_once("footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well at a guess $_POST['membersince'] is null when you set the params for the insert statement.

Comment: Why there is a closing bracket(`>`) after `<?php` in the `membersince` input field?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue but I fixed it, so would like to share, may be this will be useful to someone...

Usually when you encounter

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column NAME_OF_YOUR_COLUMN

This generally occurs if the variable is not set, in your case, the key which is causing this issue is

```
<input class="text" name="membersince" 
       value=" <?php> $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d"); echo $todaysdate?>" 
       type="text" disabled>
```

So if you see here, you are using `disabled` attribute for this particular field hence, your `form` element won't send the value of this field to the server, hence... when you use the below in your query

```
':membersince' => $_POST['membersince']
```

Will result in `null` as there's no key of `membersince` in `$_POST` array. So make sure the variable you are assigning should be set.

Comment: Not sure about the -1.. but, 1+.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I was recently serially down voted twice :) and thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use `readonly` instead of `disabled`. disabled field value cannot be post through `form` tag.

```
<input class="text" name="membersince" 
       value=" <?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" 
       type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem. The 'field name' in my form and the column name of database was different. My problem was:
     `"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'MoneyMethod' cannot be null"`. 
My form input tag:`{!! Form::select("MoneyMethod", $MoneymethodInfo, null,["class"=>"form-control MoneyMethod required","id"=>"MoneyMethod"]) !!}`, notice the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' and in my database table `$table->string('MoneyMethod', 100);` the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' is same as form but in my controller `$riskfund->Moneymethod  = Input::get('Moneymethod');` look carefully the spelling of 'Moneymethod' differs from my form and database table column. After correcting the spelling, it is working now.
So, please check the spelling of 'membersince' in form, controller, database table. it may help you.